# How to convert a number to month in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a column like a, and its value like 1, 2, 3, 4, etc stands for each month. 1 stands for January. Now I want to select the data and shown as January, what function should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `PARSE_DATE` to convert your number to a date and then extract the month name using `FORMAT_DATE` with the parameter `%B`.

Note that `month_column` is your column name

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE( "%B", PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m-%d",CONCAT('2000-',month_column,'-01') ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below option

```
select col_number,
  format_date('%B', date(2020, col_number, 1)) col_month
from your_table
```

with output

[image]